# Linux - rename all files by replacing last hyphen with '##'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Please anyone.

How do I in Linux rename a bunch of files like:

```
abc-def-0001.xxx
acb-def-0002.xxx
```

to:

```
abc-def##0001.xxx
...
```

I have tried several suggestions from SO like:

```
rename 's/(.*)-/$1##/' *.xxx
```

But didn't worked as expected in my environment.

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean?

Comment: No files were renamed.

Comment: So what is your environment? On my `bash` your command works fine.

Comment: rename (util-linux-ng 2.17.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed "s/\(.*\)-/\1##/"`"; done
```

I think my version of the rename command does not support the perl expressions...

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookahead in your regex:

```
rename -n 's/-(?=\d)/##/' *.xxx
```

This will match & replace first `_` that is followed by a digit.

However your pattern `'s/(.*)-/$1##/'` would also work for given examples but this assumes you're always replacing last underscore.

Comment: And don't forget that people who are creating filenames which contain characters such as '#', will face eternal damnation ... While it is permitted, some characters (#, %, \, space, ....) are used so much in other contexts, that you are just inviting trouble.