# Linux rename cannot replace hyphen

Tags: linux, rename

I want to remove the last `-2` in these files:

```
$ ls ./
ZVul-1-2s-0-C1-2.fit  ZVul-1-2s-2-C1-2.fit  ZVul-2-2s-1-C2-2.fit

$ rename "-2.fit" ".fit" ./*
rename: invalid option -- '2'
Try 'rename --help' for more information.

$ rename -V
rename from util-linux 2.37.2

$ ls ./
ZVul-1-2s-0-C1-2.fit  ZVul-1-2s-2-C1-2.fit  ZVul-2-2s-1-C2-2.fit
```

It regard my hyphen as an option. What can I do?

I have tried `rename -n 's/-(?=\d)//' *.xxx` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626662/linux-rename-all-files-by-replacing-last-hyphen-with) but not work, it seems that this is the C++ version which does not support Perl regs.

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed "s/\(.*\)-2/\1/"`"; done
```

This works. But `rename` should be easier.

Comment: `rename -- "-2.fit" ".fit" ./*`

Answer (score 0):

`rename -- "-2.fit" ".fit" ./*` by @KamilCuk is an answer, Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).